# Looking for a paper on Weakly uniform bases

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I want to find an old paper:

R.W. Heath, R.W. Lindgren, Weakly uniform bases, HOUSTON JOURNAL OF MATHEMATICS. 2(1) (1976) 85–90

Could someone help me? A link is also welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Found it http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=C470A9220900AE8AF2B321F45688BEE4?doi=10.1.1.445.8077&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: @GregoryGrant: Thank you very much. Good job! Very appreciated!

Comment: No prob, thank google!